# Python script not saving csv to specified location

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a python script for a program I'm trying to run that is attempting to save a .csv file to the downloads folder on my computer. The script runs without errors but it's not saving the file to the specified location. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define function to analyze student performance, interests, and learning style
def create_customized_lesson_plan(student_id):
  # Read in student data from a csv file
  student_data = pd.read_csv('/Users/jmeszaros/Downloads/student_data.csv')

  # Extract the relevant data for the specified student
  student_row = student_data[student_data["student_id"] == student_id]
  performance_data = student_row["performance"]
  interests_data = student_row["interests"]
  learning_style = student_row["learning_style"]

  # Analyze the data to determine the student's strengths and interests
  strengths = []
  interests = []
  if "math" in interests_data and performance_data["math"] > 80:
    strengths.append("math")
  if "science" in interests_data and performance_data["science"] > 80:
    strengths.append("science")
  if "history" in interests_data:
    interests.append("history")
  if "art" in interests_data:
    interests.append("art")

  # Create a customized lesson plan based on the student's strengths and interests
  lesson_plan = []
  if "math" in strengths:
    lesson_plan.append("Math game: Solve challenging math problems to earn points and unlock new levels")
  if "science" in strengths:
    lesson_plan.append("Science simulation: Explore the solar system and learn about the planets and their characteristics")
  if "history" in interests:
    lesson_plan.append("History quiz: Test your knowledge of historical events and figures")
  if "art" in interests:
    lesson_plan.append("Art project: Create your own masterpiece using different art materials and techniques")

  # Create a dataframe for the lesson plan
  lesson_plan_df = pd.DataFrame({"activity": lesson_plan})

  # Save the lesson plan to a csv file
  lesson_plan_df.to_csv('/Users/jmeszaros/Downloads/lesson_plan_' + student_id + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Is this the line you are referring to?  lesson_plan_df.to_csv('/Users/jmeszaros/Downloads/lesson_plan_' + student_id + '.csv', index=False) If so, is the file elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe you don't call the function. You could print the target directory just before the save.

Comment: Also you may want to print out the first few lines of `lesson_plan_df` prior to saving it, just to confirm that it actually contains data (`print(lesson_plan_df.head(5))`).

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you! Yeah I tried printing lesson_plan_df and it returned nothing. There is definitely data in the .csv file I'm calling but its not comma delimited, which I'm not sure if that matters when using the to_csv function.

Comment: The function has no early returns so either it raised an error (you should see a traceback message if you run at the console) or you didn't call the function at all. If this is your full script, that's the problem. Something needs to call create_customized_lesson_plan with a student_id.